# Stretched 90 degree angle Bevel

Tags: bevel

So i wanna do a bevel on an edge but all the options except percentage one are doing it like the edge is at some weird angle and does not divide the faces equally, even though the original has a 90 degree angle. I dont see any problems with the normals here though the mesh has some ngons (though not connected in any way to this corner).

This problem does not accure with any other mesh in a scene.

[image: An example]

Comment: ... Ctrl A  > apply the scale of your object?

Comment: @RobinBetts Hey, Robin. Thanks for answering. I try to keep my scale at 1.0 so i use Apply all transforms to deltas from time to time, but i guess it is a little different thing, because if i apply scale it actually stretches this whole object.

Answer (score 2):

The terminology is confusing. 'Applying' to Deltas is not the same as ['Applying'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/227327/35559)

'Applying' transforms is baking object transforms into the mesh. 'Applying' to Deltas is transferring object-level transforms to a secondary transform matrix. Really, the Delta transforms are useful only in animation, when you want to keep a zero-point handy, to return to.

When you 'Apply to Deltas', the object is still carrying an object-level transform, just in a different place. The 3 Bevels below are: 1. with the object carrying a non-uniform scale, 2. with the scale 'Applied to Delta', 3. with the scale truly 'Applied'.

[image]

Bevelling before Applying object-level scale is the same thing as scaling *after* bevelling. That's the internal order of events. There really is never any need to scale in Object Mode during modelling, except, perhaps, when setting 'Dimensions', in that panel. Avoid, whenever possible, the most common cause of questions on BSE. :)