# Edges of clearly different size display same edge length

Tags: edges, scale, units, measurement

I am very new to blender and working on my first model: a bed. I'm trying to model it with real world measurements, but I'm having a really hard time.

I'm using Blender 2.93a and have a scaled cube for the mattress and one for the base of the bed. The edge length for the height of the mattress is 30cm and while the height of the base is visibly around twice the mattress' height, its measurements are still the same or less.

[image: screenshot of a corner of the bed where one height edge says 30cm and another that is clearly 2 times the size says 30.2cm]

[image: screenshot of a corner of the bed where one height edge says 30cm and another that is clearly 2 times the size says 28.4cm]

I scaled the larger edge below 30cm to be sure and it's still longer than the 30cm edge.

---

*What could be causing these inconsistencies and how do I fix it?
Also can I input exactly what dimensions I want for edges or for a whole cuboid?*

Comment: This could be the result of non-uniform scale - it happens when you scale in Object Mode instead of Edit Mode. To fix it, select the object in Object Mode and press Ctrl+A (apply) and select _scale_.

Comment: Maybe have a look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/227327/35559)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DNR: Scale operations in object mode remember the scale but don't actually apply it.  You need a separate apply step.

Here is a simple example to explain what people are telling you in the comments

- Add a cube
- In *Edit* mode enable edge length in overlays menu.

[image: top panel showing edge length]

- In *Object* mode scale the cube to 1/10 of its size along the Z axis (shortcut <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>)
- In *Object* mode the side panel will show that you've scaled Z and that it's now 0.2 m as you'd expect:

[image: side panel showing scale and length]

- In *Edit* mode, the edge length measurements will show the original size:

[image: edge measurements]

That is because scaling in object mode doesn't apply the scale change but only remembers it and uses it to draw.  To fix your measurements

- In *Object* mode *apply* the scale (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>S</kbd>) and select *Scale* from the apply menu:

[image: apply menu showing scale]

- Now the *Object* mode side panel will show the same length for Z but the Z scale will be 1:

[image: dimensions and scale when scale is applied]

- and the *Edit* mode measurements will show the same thing:

[image: edit mode measurements now match object mode]

Comment: Woof.  Thanks for this